# What exactly does multicast() do?

Tags: apache-camel

What's the exact difference between

```
from("stream:in")
.to("stream:out", "stream:err");
```

and

```
from("stream:in")
.multicast()
.to("stream:out", "stream:err");
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case - no real difference, since the incoming message body for the `stream` camel component seems to always be sent onwards as the outgoing message body ;)

Imagine however a more substantial case, for example:

```
from("stream:in")
    .to("direct:one", "direct:two");
```

In this case, whatever is received on the stream is first sent to route `direct:one`. Now, if that route modifies the message in some way (e.g. `setBody(constant("modified"))`, then route `direct:two` will received the *modified* outgoing message from the route `direct:one`.

Think of it like this: `stream:in` -> `direct:one` -> `direct:two`.

**Multicast**

```
from("stream:in")
    .multicast()
    .to("direct:one", "direct:two");
```

In contrast, with multicast, whatever is received on the stream is firstly sent to `direct:one`, and that same message body from the stream (as a copy) is sent to `direct:two` - regardless of what `direct:one` sets as it's outgoing message body.

We can think of the multicast like this:

```
stream:in -----> direct:one
          \----> direct:two
```

Comment: Ah.. subtle. A bit like serial vs. parallel electrical connections. Thank you for this elaborate answer.

Comment: Great! Would you mind to accept the answer, if you are happy with it?

Comment: multicast is not parallel by default; If you want concurrent/parallel processing though multicast, then you need to enable parallelProcessing.